# open board "quit unexpectedly" when I try to "Podcast"

Tags: mac, big-sur

In open board software, there is an option to podcast the video.

When I try to do that, the open board quit unexpectedly and shows the following error. I posted only some part of the error, it is too big to post here.

```
Process:               OpenBoard [9847]
Path:                  /Applications/OpenBoard.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenBoard
Identifier:            org.oe-f.OpenBoard
Version:               1.5.4 (1.5.4)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           OpenBoard [9847]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-09-06 00:06:13.581 +0530
OS Version:            macOS 11.5.2 (20G95)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        82DAF92D-590E-7463-C36D-BA77F36BF1F7

Sleep/Wake UUID:       707F53A8-2266-48B6-90DC-06DB3058256E

Time Awake Since Boot: 65000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [9847]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libavutil.56.dylib              0x000000010e5d6a2d av_opt_set_defaults2 + 332

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdffbf6a28 0x7ffdffbf2000 + 18984
1   runtime                         0x00007ffdffbfbeec 0x7ffdffbf2000 + 40684
2   runtime                         0x00007ffdffbfd2c0 0x7ffdffbf2000 + 45760

Thread 2:: WebCore: IconDatabase
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20327cde __psynch_cvwait + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x00000001114d6fcb 0x110f6e000 + 5672907
3   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x00000001114d6db9 0x110f6e000 + 5672377
4   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011238d76f 0x110f6e000 + 21100399
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 3:: JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20327cde __psynch_cvwait + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209e118 0x110f6e000 + 18022680
3   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011238d76f 0x110f6e000 + 21100399
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 4:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20327cde __psynch_cvwait + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209efa7 0x110f6e000 + 18026407
3   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209f038 0x110f6e000 + 18026552
4   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011238d76f 0x110f6e000 + 21100399
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 5:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20327cde __psynch_cvwait + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209efa7 0x110f6e000 + 18026407
3   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209f038 0x110f6e000 + 18026552
4   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011238d76f 0x110f6e000 + 21100399
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 6:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20327cde __psynch_cvwait + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209efa7 0x110f6e000 + 18026407
3   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209f038 0x110f6e000 + 18026552
4   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011238d76f 0x110f6e000 + 21100399
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 7:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20327cde __psynch_cvwait + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209efa7 0x110f6e000 + 18026407
3   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209f038 0x110f6e000 + 18026552
4   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011238d76f 0x110f6e000 + 21100399
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 8:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20327cde __psynch_cvwait + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209efa7 0x110f6e000 + 18026407
3   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209f038 0x110f6e000 + 18026552
4   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011238d76f 0x110f6e000 + 21100399
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 9:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20327cde __psynch_cvwait + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209efa7 0x110f6e000 + 18026407
3   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011209f038 0x110f6e000 + 18026552
4   org.qt-project.QtWebKit         0x000000011238d76f 0x110f6e000 + 21100399
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 10:: Qt bearer thread
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20329d62 __pselect + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011075a398 qt_safe_select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timespec const*) + 104
3   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011075b450 QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate::doSelect(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>, timespec*) + 672
4   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011075c51a QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 234
5   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011070907d QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 381
6   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011055d245 QThread::exec() + 117
7   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000110560d93 0x110529000 + 228755
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 11:: UBFeaturesComputingThread
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20327cde __psynch_cvwait + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011056241b 0x110529000 + 234523
3   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x00000001105622d2 QWaitCondition::wait(QMutex*, unsigned long) + 162
4                                   0x0000000102e98892 UBFeaturesComputingThread::run() + 402
5   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000110560d93 0x110529000 + 228755
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 12:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203252ba mach_msg_trap + 10
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20453855 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20451f0b __CFRunLoopRun + 1332
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20451310 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22d0923a _NSEventThread + 124
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 13:: Qt HTTP thread
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20329d62 __pselect + 10
2   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011075a398 qt_safe_select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timespec const*) + 104
3   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011075b450 QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate::doSelect(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>, timespec*) + 672
4   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011075c51a QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 234
5   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011070907d QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 381
6   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000011055d245 QThread::exec() + 117
7   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000110560d93 0x110529000 + 228755
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 14:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdffc147c8 0x7ffdffbf2000 + 141256

Thread 15:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdffc147c8 0x7ffdffbf2000 + 141256

Thread 16:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdffc147c8 0x7ffdffbf2000 + 141256

Thread 17:: AMCP Logging Spool
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203252f6 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
2   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff28666836 caulk::semaphore::timed_wait(double) + 110
3   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff28666784 caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::run() + 30
4   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff28666502 void* caulk::thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<caulk::thread::attributes, void (caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::*)(), std::__1::tuple<caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread*> > >(void*) + 45
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 18:
0   ???                             0x00007ffe945928f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2032530e semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff201b1145 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 58
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff201bf656 _dispatch_worker_thread + 284
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2035a8fc _pthread_start + 224
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20356443 thread_start + 15

Thread 19:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdffc147c8 0x7ffdffbf2000 + 141256

Thread 20:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdffc147c8 0x7ffdffbf2000 + 141256

Thread 21:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdffc147c8 0x7ffdffbf2000 + 141256

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000010e5d6a1b  rbx: 0x00007fe04e4a530c  rcx: 0x0000000000000001  rdx: 0x00007fe04e4a530c
  rdi: 0x00007fe04e4a4e00  rsi: 0x000000010c4dac10  rbp: 0x000000010c4dac10  rsp: 0x000000030a78faa0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x00007fe04e3f3e00  r10: 0x0000000000000001  r11: 0x000000010e5d68d8
  r12: 0x000000010e5d6a5c  r13: 0x00007fe04e4a4e00  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x000000010e5d6a2d  rfl: 0x0000000000000203
```

How do I fix this issue and how can I record the open board and post in YouTube.

Comment: What did the developers say when you asked them about their software?

Comment: @Tetsujin I did not ask anyone :O